# Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen not working on screen lock

Tags: android

In my android application i have declared my screens as full screen in the manifest as below

```
<activity android:name=".ContentDisplay"  
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

It works fine normally but when the screen gets locked a black layer appears on top shifting the screen downwards.Attached is the images.

[image: After Screen Lock]

[image: Before screen Lock]

Please let me know what i can do for resolving this.

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same problem when I use TabHost. Here are a workaround for this problem:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

This is drawn first with the notification bar and redrawn after the ms.

The best solution, if you don't use TabHost.